# My serialization function crashes my app

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

```
public static void Serialize(List<Zajecia> xml_List)
{            
      XmlSerializer Xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Zajecia>));
      MemoryStream file =new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("C:\test.xml"));            
      TextWriter Txt = new StreamWriter(file);
      Xml.Serialize(Txt,xml_List);
      Txt.Dispose();
}
```

This function just dont work I guess. When I trying to call it my app just crash. Similar code I used to use on desktop programs and it was working corectly. Don't know how to make it on metro app.

Comment: A crashed app usually provides exceptions.  You're not going to get much help unless you provide them.

Comment: `C:\test.xml` is OK for a desktop app but disallowed in the Metro environment.

Comment: hm... So how to make it work? there must be a way to serialize in metro apps

Comment: and about exception... there is just no exception (don't know how is it possible) it just highlight part of code

<code>    #if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif    <code>

Comment: _how to make it work?_ - look for IsolatedStorage. This is very basic Win8 stuff.